# Is there a Google Earth control available in the iPad SDK?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, ipad, google-earth-plugin

Is there a Google Earth control available in the iPad SDK or someway of having google earth inside my new iPad app?

Answer (score 0):

No. You can embed Google Maps content using [MapKit](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/index.html) but there is no way to embed Google Earth.

Make sure you're aware of the Google [Terms of Service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/iphone/terms.html) before you embed a map view in your app.

Comment: Isn't it possible to call Google Earth API methods as iPad touch events are triggered?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  Google Earth iPhone application on the iPad. However the only control you have over it is the ability to load custom Kml files.